# Is it possible to use kubernetes namespace quota excluding certain resources

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to use kubernetes namespace quota excluding certain resources. For example, exclude used pod resources belonging to daemonsets. Counting daemosets resources imposes an inconvenience when scaling a cluster, having to change the requestQuota resource for a large number of namespaces

**TL;DR**
tnx [Fritz Duchardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385808/fritz-duchardt), for the answer.

1. Create PriorityClass.name: daemonsets
2. Add spec.template.spec.PriorityClassName: daemonsets in ds manifest
3. Create resourceQuota

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 2Gi
  scopeSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - operator: NotIn
      scopeName: PriorityClass
      values:
      - daemonsets
```

Comment: Why having a quota like that for a namespace with DaemonSet ?

Comment: In this namespace runing not only ds pods, also deploiment pods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Limiting resource quotas to explicit K8s resources is not possible, but you could use [Priority Classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#pod-priority) in conjunction with `scopeSelectors` to achieve a similar thing. More on the topic can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#resource-quota-per-priorityclass).